# What does a.{X} mean in OCaml?

Tags: arrays, syntax, f#, ocaml

I'm currently trying to port some OCaml to F#. I'm "in at the deep end" with OCaml and my F# is a bit rusty.

Anyway, the OCaml code builds fine in the OCaml compiler, but (not surprisingly) gives a load of errors in the F# compiler even with ML compatibility switched on. Some of the errors look to be reserved words, but the bulk of the errors are complaining about the `.{` in lines such as:

```
 m.(a).(b) <- w.{a + b * c};
```

a,b,c are integers.

I've done a lot of searching through OCaml websites, Stackoverflow, the English translation of the French O'Reilly book, etc. and cannot find anything like this. Of course it doesn't help that most search facilities have problems with punctuation characters! Yes I've found references to `.` being used to refer to record members, and `{ }` being used to define records, but both together?  From the usage, I assume it is some kind of associative or sparse array?

What does this syntax mean?  What is the closest F# equivalent?

Comment: nice way to investigate such things is to ask the compiler itself - i.e. `echo let f x y = x.{y} > zz.ml && ocamlc -i zz.ml && rm zz.ml` which gives `val f : ('a, 'b, 'c) Bigarray.Array1.t -> int -> 'a`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a pdf of the oCaml documentation/manual available here:

http://caml.inria.fr/distrib/ocaml-3.12/ocaml-3.12-refman.pdf

On page 496 (toward the bottom of the page), it says of generic arrays and their get method:

> val get : (’a, ’b, ’c) t -> int array -> ’a
>
> Read an element of a generic big array. Genarray.get a [|i1; ...; iN|] returns
>   the element of a whose coordinates are i1 in the first dimension, i2 in the second
>   dimension, . . ., iN in the N-th dimension.
>
> If a has C layout, the coordinates must be greater or equal than 0 and strictly less than
>   the corresponding dimensions of a. If a has Fortran layout, the coordinates must be
>   greater or equal than 1 and less or equal than the corresponding dimensions of a. Raise
>   Invalid_argument if the array a does not have exactly N dimensions, or if the
>   coordinates are outside the array bounds.
>
> **If N > 3, alternate syntax is provided: you can write a.{i1, i2, ..., iN} instead of
>   Genarray.get a [|i1; ...; iN|]. (The syntax a.{...} with one, two or three
>   coordinates is reserved for accessing one-, two- and three-dimensional arrays as
>   described below.)**

Further, it says (specifically about one dimensional arrays):

> val get : (’a, ’b, ’c) t -> int -> ’a
>
> **Array1.get a x, or alternatively a.{x}, returns the element of a at index x.** x must
>   be greater or equal than 0 and strictly less than Array1.dim a if a has C layout. If a
>   has Fortran layout, x must be greater or equal than 1 and less or equal than
>   Array1.dim a. Otherwise, Invalid_argument is raised.

In F#, you can access array elements using the `Array.get` method as well.  But, a closer syntax would be `w.[a + b * c]`.  In short, in F#, use `[]` instead of `{}`.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the quick reply. I did see references to [|...|] notation and did wonder about a synonym for that - but saw nothing in my searches (as noted, punctuation is hard to search for). About to download the manual PDF to my iPad...

Comment: for easier reading, here's the web page version of what you were referring to: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Bigarray.Genarray.html#VALget and for one-dimensional bigarrays: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Bigarray.Array1.html#VALge (note that one-dimensional bigarrays are different from regular arrays)

Comment: `In short, in F#, use [] instead of {}.` Not really, OCaml uses `w.(i)` for Arrays. BigArrays are a special beast and are used mostly to interface with C and other languages.